# Discrepancy between "query_exec" and "bq_table_download" using bigrquery

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, google-bigquery, bigrquery

So far I used bigrquery's `query_exec` to download timeseries data from BigQuery.

```
sql <- "SELECT  Date, val1, val2
        FROM `mydata` 
        WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-06-01'"

project <- "myproj"

df <- query_exec(sql, project = project, max_pages = Inf, use_legacy_sql = FALSE) %>% as_tibble()
```

Since the last update a warning appears indicating that `query_exec` is deprecated and instead `bq_table_download` in conjuction with `bq_project_query` should be used.

```
tb <- bq_project_query(project, sql)
df <- bq_table_download(tb, page_size = 100000)
```

Adjusting my code resulted in a dataframe of the same size (more than 4 million rows) as doing the request with `query_exec`. However, from row ~80000 onwards now only dates of format 1970-01-01 appear and the remaining columns are either empty or contain zeros. Using the old way with `query_exec` still works and results in the correctly formatted dataframe.

Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to the page_size parameter that you set to 100000. If this is increased to bigger numbers the results are not properly parsed anymore and some NAs or wrongly parsed errors appear. I assume that you dates come out as 1970-01-01 because of that.

Try setting the page_size to something closer to the default 10000 and it should work. I have not yet found the perfect value, but 20000 works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I also played around with the page_size parameter to find a value for which it works properly (in my case 5000). However, depending on the dataset I request the issue still appears from time to time. By the way, there's also an ongoing dicussion on GitHub regarding that topic (https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/issues/412).

Comment: Thanks for linking to the the discussion. I'll follow that and hope for a solution :)